# How can I route all traffic coming in to an OpenVPN server through an Apache proxy on the same machine?

Tags: proxy, apache-http-server, openvpn

I was following the instructions [here](http://00f.net/2012/06/02/mod-pagespeed-as-a-proxy-for-your-phone/) to set up mod_pagespeed as a proxy for my phone. As the security note suggested, I set up OpenVPN and got that much working on my phone, but OpenVPN isn't letting any traffic through to the internet. Ideally, the traffic would go to the internet via mod_pagespeed running in an Apache proxy server on the same machine, so my workflow would involve simply connecting to the proxy on my phone and then using the phone's browser as normal, except that it's being run through my mod_pagespeed proxy.

I'll gladly take a link to the docs: I looked pretty hard, but I couldn't find anything. I'm interested in configuration instructions specific to OpenVPN.

Answer (score 0):

mod_pagespeed is new to me... first time I heard of it (sorry for the ignorance) seems interesting though.

However the problem seems to be that OpenVPN is not letting you connect to the INTERNET, if I understand correctly without Openvpn you have Internet... with it you don't right?

Can you post more details about the openvpn config?